# Spring Integration - Poller does not process next message on MessageHandlingException from JobLaunchingGateway

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-batch, spring-integration

Looking for suggestions on error handling in my Spring Integration/Spring Batch application.

**Context**

I am using an inbound file adapter to poll for files in the input directory. The file is passed as a parameter to a Spring Batch job via the JobLaunchingGateway. The job is run on its own thread pool using a TaskExecutor.

The files are moved to a processed directory when the job completes or to the error directory when the job execution fails.

The poller uses the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` which does not retain processed files between application restarts due to the cache being in-memory. This is not a concern for my application since Spring Batch would throw an exception if the same file shows up in the input directory at a later point in time.

**Issue**

Day 1 - The input file `abc_success005.csv` is processed successfully.

Several days later (application has been restarted since Day 1) -  When the same file arrived at the input directory erroneously, I noticed that the poller thread received an error from the `JobLaunchingGateway` and it did not proceed to process the subsequent messages in the *current polling cycle*.

Note that the poller resumed duties and continued operations on schedule after the polling interval expired.

The SimpleJobLauncher executes the job in a separate thread pool using the TaskExecutor. However, the creation of the job execution uses the caller's thread, which is the poller in my case.

**SimpleJobLauncher - From Spring batch source code**

```
jobExecution = jobRepository.createJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);

    try {
        taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                        logger.info("Job: [" + job + "] launched with the following parameters: [" + jobParameters
                                + "]");
                    }
                    job.execute(jobExecution);
```

My Integration flow

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myIntegrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway,
                                             FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(properties.getInputDir()))
                    .filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(50)
                    ))
            .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest)
            .handle(jobLaunchingGateway)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload")
            .get();
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[ERROR] 2022-08-15 11:59:46,853 o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler error taskExecutor-2id taskExecutor-2 - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={input_file_name=/var/tmp/batch/input/abc_success005.csv}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=JobLaunchRequest: processStuffJob, parameters={input_file_name=/var/tmp/batch/input/abc_success005.csv}, headers={file_originalFile=/var/tmp/batch/input/abc_success005.csv, id=298019a3-b548-2a26-1469-78394758d824, file_name=abc_success005.csv, file_relativePath=abc_success005.csv, timestamp=1660579186811}]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway.handleRequestMessage(JobLaunchingGateway.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:475)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={input_file_name=/var/tmp/batch/input/abc_success005.csv}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:139)
```

The poller thread typically fetches a bunch of files/messages and sends it to the JobLaunchingGateway for processing. When the job fails to launch, the poller does not handle the exception and hence the processing of the rest of the file terminates.

I understand that this doesn't stop the poller from resuming next cycle but it is not desirable for one bad file to end the current polling cycle. This can also lead to situations where one bad file (when left as is) as potentially cause the issue in repeat in several following polling cycles.

**Form Spring Integration source code - AbstractPollingEndpoint**

```
    private Runnable createPoller() {
    return () ->
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
}
```

What is the recommended solution in this case?

One option I can think of is to extend the JobLaunchingGateway and deal with the file (move to error directory) + log/swallow this exception. From a functional standpoint, there is not much to be done here other than moving the file out + log the error.

I am writing this to seek better solutions. I think it is not desirable for one bad file to starve the execution of other files (even within a polling cycle)

Comment: `I noticed that the poller thread received an error from the JobLaunchingGateway and it did not proceed to process the subsequent messages in the current polling cycle.` Can you share the error here? Is it the same as the stacktrace you shared? (BTW, that stacktrace is incomplete, please post the full trace). IIUC, the issue here is with the poller, not Spring Batch per se. I see Spring Batch rejecting the same file that was successfully processed as expected. The poller should not stop the current polling cycle if an error occurs while submitting a job request for the current file.

Comment: Fadhel - The stack trace is from the poller thread. Below is the rest of it. The error log was from the default error handler of the poller. The poller thread went back to the `taskexecutor` pool. Next polling cycle resumed. But, it is not desirable that current cycle stopped.

```
 at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The poller thread typically fetches a bunch of files/messages and sends it to the JobLaunchingGateway for processing.

That's not correct. See `FileReadingMessageSource`. It does fetch on a first request:

```
protected AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<File> doReceive() {
    // rescan only if needed or explicitly configured
    if (this.scanEachPoll || this.toBeReceived.isEmpty()) {
        scanInputDirectory();
    }

    File file = this.toBeReceived.poll();
```

And we produce only one from that queue to the mentioned `if (pollForMessage() == null) {`

That's true that current polling cycle is cancelled in case of error, but we don't ignore the other cached files. We just comes back to the next `this.toBeReceived.poll()` in the next polling cycle.

It just was designed that way day first: the `maxMessagesPerPoll` is a part of single polling cycle unit of work. As well as all the messages we poll from a single executor's task. So, failure somewhere in the middle of task is like a task cancelling.

If you still find this as an inappropriate, see if `maxMessagesPerPoll = 1` is OK for you, so you single polling cycle is going to be for a single file.

Another solution is to catch an exception on that `.handle(jobLaunchingGateway)` and don't let it pass back to the poller. See an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Artem. I meant that poller would typically continue making more files available for processing if there was no error. 

Setting maxMessagesPerPoll=1 is not desirable as we want infrequent polls but working on multiple files at a time. 
I don't want the poller cycle to terminate due to a single message failure. There is no connection b/w the files and one shouldn't affect the other. 

I will look into ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice. It's either that or I can extend the JobLaunchingGateway to log/swallow the exception + move the file to invalid directory.

Comment: You can also use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to survive an application restart and don't deal with already filtered files. You also can really move those files to archive dir after their process in the job. Re. poller again: you need to treat it as a single unit of work. This is a task we schedule for the executor. It is just a part of the task to have that loop around `maxMessagesPerPoll`. It probably feels more natural when we also have a transaction around this task. So, or we insert all the data (`maxMessagesPerPoll`) to DB or rollback - the whole polling cycle.

Comment: Not too concerned about accidentally re-processing same file as we have Spring Batch behind the scenes to handle that. Would prefer that over `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` since we want ability to "resume" same file if job failed due to a downstream issue. We expect to manually move same file back from error dir. Note that file modified time will not change. Re: poll, it is desirable for us to treat each file as separate unit of work but not poll frequently. We would like to poll every few mins and don't want to defer processing till next cycle due to one bad accidental file.

Comment: Well, you can poll more frequently and in parallel. You do parallel with the `fixedRate` right now, but I see 5 mins poll delay. If no new files, nothing happens, it just comes back to similar "void" polling cycle. You can do a conditional intervals. See `SimpleActiveIdleReceiveMessageAdvice` for that purpose: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers

Comment: Actually, `fixedRate` is not polling in parallel. My initial expectation was that there will be multiple threads polling in parallel. But, it turns out that there is just one thread polling at any given time. The way I see it - the scheduler initiates polling on a task executor. A new thread is assigned for every polling cycle until the number of task executor threads reach the core size. So, technically, there are multiple threads in the pool but I am noticing only one thread doing the poll for any given cycle. If that is not the expected behavior, I will post a new question with details.

Comment: Well, you said yourself `fixedRate = 5 mins` - the next poll happens after 5 mins of the previous one has started. The `fixedDelay` difference that it starts a new poll when the previous finishes. With fixed rate it might be parallel only if the current task is too slow. If you really want to parallel those `maxMessagesPerPoll`, consider to use an `ExecutorChannel` as an output of this polling channel adapter. Add `channel(c -> c.executor())` before your `.transform()`

Comment: Does the `ExecutorChannel' also effectively decouple the poller from the output of the `JobLaunchingGateway'? As in, does the poller move to the next message after submitting the message to the executor channel?

Comment: Yes, it does. And in this case you don't need that `.taskExecutor(taskExecutor()` on the poller. The `pollForMessage()` does its job by sending a message to that channel and comes back for the next one in that loop. The currently sent message is processed on the other thread and error from there won't effect the next message.

Comment: Great idea. Such decoupling - a)processing thread decoupling and b) functional message handling decoupling - was my original objective. I think an intermediate executor channel makes it more elegant. Thank you!

Does the `taskExecutor' still help in any way? I liked that processing errors during polling did not kill the poller for the next cycle. Can same behavior be expected from if polling happens on scheduler thread?

Comment: It will. You just send a message to the channel and forget. There is just no reason in extra async step - the scheduled thread is OK to abuse for such a simple short task.