# How to set up ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice to stop task from being cancelled

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a scenario which I'm not sure if I am setting up correctly in Integration Flow.
The need is to:

- Poll SFTP location for files
- Transfer all that are new / have been changed and store that information with `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`
- On failure continue with the next available file

For the last point I have found in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73377044) that I could try an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.
I have came up with the following configuration, but adding the `Advice` has broken the flow completely (no message is flowing through)

```
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
advice.setSuccessChannel(out);
advice.setFailureChannel(err);
advice.setTrapException(true);

IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
        .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(cachingSessionFactory)
        .remoteDirectory("sftpSource")
        .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
        .preserveTimestamp(true)
        .localDirectory(getTargetLocalDirectory()), e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(3)
                        .advice(advice)))
        .channel(out)
        .get();
```

The requirement for skipping a filed file transfer came out from a real world scenario, where our SFTP server refused to transfer an empty file. To simulate this I have added spies to the `SessionFactory`:

```
CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> cachingSessionFactory = Mockito.spy(sessionFactory());
CachingSessionFactory.CachedSession session = (CachingSessionFactory.CachedSession) Mockito.spy(cachingSessionFactory.getSession());

doReturn(session).when(cachingSessionFactory).getSession();
doThrow(new RuntimeException("test exception")).when(session).read(contains("sftpSource2.txt"), any(OutputStream.class));
```

and the test code:

```
Message<?> message = out.receive(1000);
assertThat(message).isNotNull();
Object payload = message.getPayload();
assertThat(payload).isInstanceOf(File.class);
File file = (File) payload;
assertThat(file.getName()).isEqualTo(" sftpSource1.txt");
assertThat(file.getAbsolutePath()).contains("localTarget");

message = out.receive(1000);
assertThat(message).isNull();

message = err.receive(1000);
System.out.println("error was:" + message.getPayload());

message = out.receive(1000);
assertThat(message).isNotNull();
file = (File) message.getPayload();
assertThat(file.getName()).isIn("sftpSource3.txt");
assertThat(file.getAbsolutePath()).contains("localTarget");
```

What I am confused about is - when I added the `advice` to the `Poller` should I remove `.errorChannel(err)` from the `Poller`? But if the advice is handling where the message ends up, shouldn't I also remove `.channel(out)` on the `integrationFlow`? Without it the IntegrationFlow doesn't build, with error `outputChannel is required`.

My second worry is - if `advice.setTrapException(true);` does it mean `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` will mark the file as successfully processed? (the filter isn't present in the example code, but I will require it in real code).

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is for consumer endpoints, not a source polling channel adapters. So, you cannot handle errors from the poller using that advice.

Indeed you cannot have an `IntegrationFlow` just with a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` - you need to add that `channel(out)` either way.

Not clear by your current configuration where you transfer those files. So, probably you are talking about an error for handling those files, there that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` would make sense over there. This way indeed all your remote files would be transferred to the local dir and marked in the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` as watched. Just because you won't throw an exception from the handler back to the SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter.

Comment: The transfer would be from SFTP to a local directory where another process will pick the file for other processing. The error comes from the server.
Could you suggest a correct configuration for this use case? Still including the persistent filter, and the process to continue in case of errors, but skip the faulty file (until next polling period).

Comment: "until next polling period" - I believe this is exactly what happens by default: when error on fetching, we rollback the filter state and let the poller to pass for the next polling cycle. You may look into a `maxFetchSize(1)` option on the `Sftp.inboundAdapter()` to not rollback the whole fetched remaining batch, but just deal with one file as is.

Comment: I have changed `maxFetchSize(1)` on the adapter but see no difference in my test - `sftpSource1.txt` transfers and reads from `out` channel. An error occurs during `sftpSource2.txt` transfer and then when reading the `out` Channel every time after - it returns `null`

Comment: Well, see the logic in the framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/synchronizer/AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java#L396-L419. Perhaps it is time for you to share with us a simple project, so we can reproduce and see what else could be done to rollback failed file and come back to it later. Although it might be the problem of your `session` mock: you always throw an exception for that `sftpSource2.txt`. Therefore it might never go further for that `sftpSource3.txt`.